# importing an existing site into Drupal

Tags: mamp, drupal-8

I'm new to drupal. I have a project were I am trying to setup an existing Drupal project on my local system, using MAMP.

I've installed MAMP and added Drupal to the htdocs, but I'm unclear on how to replace the new Drupal site I created with the existing project.

Has anyone done this before?